# How is the Nitrate Ion (NO3) formed?

Tags: lewis-structure

I understand how the nitrite $\ce{NO2}$ ion can be formed and have a negative charge, but the nitrate $\ce{NO3}$ ion is confusing me. I made some simple drawings to try to explain what I don't understand:

[image]

Does the "electron from outside" that the oxygen receives, as indicated in the drawing, comes from the nitrogen atom? If so, then the N atom would be left with only 4 valence electrons instead of 5, thus being able to form another covalent bond with the extra oxygen, forming $\ce{NO3}$. Is this the correct line of thinking?

Answer (score 3):

An organiker would look at it this way.

[image: Nitrate resonance forms]

An inorganiker might look at it as literal N(+5) with two double-bonded oxygens.  It does redox as N(+5). Coordination structures are varied,

[image: Nirate coordination]

Comment: I was under the impression that organic chemists have a much greater tendency to expand octets than inorganic ones …

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about it like literally adding O to the nitrite ion then yes, the *two electrons* the oxygen receives are from nitrogen. Imagine moving the nitrogen lone pair to the oxygen to give it a full octet and forming a single bond in the process.  You will notice that the Lewis structures will match the "organiker" structures of Uncle Al.